# move_uploaded_file - file name of image?

Tags: javascript, php

**The Script:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This script also uses javascript for multiple image upload.

This script works fine, though when the ***multiple*** files get moved into the "uploads" folder the file names come out like this:

```
"2f594262c1f8fb56c39cc01d4543bcb9.jpg"
"2f594262c1f8fb56c39cc01d4543bcb9.jpgf00008a16882f01d2bd7ed6d9805a4bf.jpg"
"2f594262c1f8fb56c39cc01d4543bcb9.jpgf00008a16882f01d2bd7ed6d9805a4bf.jpge967f7fbaea4e2aee9b6f56067739aed.jpg"
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is problem ? didnt get u

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but to check if the uploaded file is of a certain type, do NOT trust the extension. Check the mime type instead. By the way, to fix your issue, move `$target_path = "uploads/";` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your `$target_path` inside the for loop. Right now you're just continually appending to it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array
    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
```